# Ubuntu 18.04 Desktop not booting up

Tags: boot, dual-boot

I'm a newbie to the whole Ubuntu and Linux thing. I'm using `Ubuntu 18.04` desktop installed on an SSD hard disk and recently every time I boot my machine Ubuntu **freezes** once I try to enter the password and I can't do anything. When I enter the recovery mode then hit resume boot normally everything works fine.
I already tried to google the problem but am not sure what I am looking for exactly.

I'm using a `Lenovo idea Thinkpad 310` with dual-boot (Win 10 on another hard drive).

Answer (score 0):

press Ctrl+Alt+F3 and see if you can log in in a terminal. If that works, Ctrl+Alt+F7 and see if you can type the same password in the login window (lightdm),if it fails, but no response in the window mode, switch to the terminal again and check the error messages.

Comment: after pressing ctrl+alt+f3 a black screen showed up with this output repeated like a hundreds of time
`fifo: SCHED_ERROR 06 []`
then the screen got frozen again